# Redis Rate Limiting in Spring Cloud Gateway, is Redis clears rate limit keys by itself?

Tags: spring, redis, rate-limiting

I implemented redis rate limiting technology. It filters all requests according to user's id and url in request. It is ready Spring's solution (using `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ratelimit.RedisRateLimiter`) with some customization.
Is Redis delete keys? Or it keeps the keys for ratelimiting forever, and I need to delete them somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the key will deleted automatically by Redis. Since the Lua script  that RedisRateLimiter uses, set expire time for these keys. Check [the source code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/30f5990517312024b1c1faa1774aa6555d588a7a/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/resources/META-INF/scripts/request_rate_limiter.lua) for detail.

NOTE: There's a more efficient solution for rate limiting, i.e. you don't need to call Redis for each request. Check [this PR](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/pull/3016) for detail.